# Return type error message

Tags: java, return

```
public class Key {

    public Encode() {
        StringBuffer passWord = new StringBuffer("bubbles");
        System.out.println("Original plain text:" + passWord);

        for (int i = 0; i < passWord.length(); i++) {
            int temp = 0;
            temp=(int)passWord.charAt(i);
            temp=  temp* 9;
            EncodedText = passWord.setCharAt(i , (char)temp);
            return EncodedText;
        }

        //return EncodedText;
    } 

}
```

Just writing a small program to encode (and decode) a small piece of text, but whenever I run it the same error message appears

"error: invalid method declaration; return type required
    public Encode() { "
           ^

Comment: if you don't want to return make the return type `void`, or course `return EncodedText;` will then be an error.

Comment: If this is a method, you need to declare it with the appropriate return type.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer is you can, use StringBuilder instead.  BTW multiplying by 9 is more likely to manage the text than encoding it.

Answer (score 1):

Your method has no return type.  It needs this so that it knows what type of data it returns.

```
public <type goes here> Encode() {
```

This

```
EncodedText = passWord.setCharAt(i , (char)temp);
```

Doesn't make sense. `EncodedText` is a class, it needs an instance before you assign to it. Should maybe be

```
EncodedText variableName = passWord.setCharAt(i , (char)temp);
```

But is probably more like (I don't know without seeing that class)

```
EncodedText variableName = new EncodedText(passWord.setCharAt(i , (char)temp));
```

And this

```
return EncodedText;
```

Also doesn't make sense, this is trying to return a class, perhaps you meant to return the instance of the class

```
return variableName;
```

in which case, in the first error, you probably meant

```
public EncodedText Encode() {
```

Other than that, there are a few other errors I can't properly diagnose without seeing the `EncodedText` class.  Errors like returning while in a loop that seems to be building an `EncodedText` object and lack of creation of said object.

Answer (score 0):

You have several errors here.

1. Your method has no return type.
2. EncodedText has no type.
3. You don't want your `return` in the for loop, it makes the loop useless as it will return in the first iteration.
4. `setCharAt()` has void as return type, you can not assign it to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put a return type (such as String, int, double, etc.), probably StringBuffer in this case, between the `public` and `Encode()`. Try doing `public StringBuffer Encode() {...}`

Answer (score 0):

Also you are not following proper Java naming-convention. It should be like:

```
public returnType methodName(dataType parameter1, dataType parameter2){
}
```

e.g.

```
public int add(int a, int b){
   return a+b;
}
```

for naming convention standards, refer:
http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm